# What causes the "args":[...] array with Json?

Tags: javascript, json, socket.io

I'm doing:

```
function uploadFile(location,slides,name){

    var data = {
        slides: slides,
        name : name
    }

    io.sockets.in('conversionRoom').emit('selectSlides',data);
```

And at the other end it comes out as:

```
{
  "name": "selectSlides",
  "args": [
    {
      "slides": [
        "2",
        "4"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like it to be:

```
{
  "name": "selectSlides",
      "slides": [
        "2",
        "4"
      ]
}
```

So that it can fit in my schema.
What's causing  the "args" to appear, and how can I make it go away?

I'm listening for the emit in C#, using Socketio-4net

```
Program.socket.On("selectSlides", (fn2) =>
            {
                Program.toLog.Add("selectSlides hit");
                var jString = fn2.Json.ToJsonString();
                Program.toLog.Add(jString); 

            });
```

Comment: What's you handler look like that listens for the `emit()`.  Because I don't think your using that API right.

Comment: @AlexWayne I edited my question with this information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't change it if you are using socket io.  You could write raw data to the socket yourself without any library at all, but then you wouldn't have all the nice features of socket io.

I have no idea how that C# library work but perhaps it's not pulling the arguments out for you.

---

Why?

Well I'm fairly sure that is simply the transport schema that socket io uses.  You need to put the args in their own object so that they do not interfere with the other keys.  For instance, what if you had an event named `setName` that expected a `name`?

```
{
    "name": "setName",
    "args": {
      "name": "Bob"
    }
}
```

Given that info, the way you want to structure is would not work:

```
// wat?!
{
    "name": "setName",
    "name": "Bob"
}
```

Because the `name` of the event and the data key `name` would conflict.

When you use the socket io JS libraries they abstract this for you passing the args to the listener handling that event.  If you just listen to the raw socket, you get the raw data and have to do that yourself.